# RxSwift, chain dependent downloads returning same Observable type

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm downloading a list of books from an API, and for each book I want to download its cover image.

I'm stuck with what I think it's a very simple and common task in Rx. I've done a research but I cannot find the solution because all the related questions are about how to return another `Observable`; for example get Github repositories and then get the issues for each one, but returning `Observable<Issue>` not a modified `Observable<Repository>`, that is my case. In my case I want to modify the previous observable result (`Observable<[Book]>`) with the result of another request returning different observable (`Observable<Data>`).

For now I have the first part, download books:

```
func search(query: String) -> Observable<[Book]> {
    return networkSession.rx
        .data(request: URLRequest(url: url))
        .map({ try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: $0) })
}
```

`Book` is a simple struct:

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let authors: [String]
    let coverImageURL: URL
    var coverImage: Data?
}
```

After that I'm able to download each image but I don't know how to assign it to each object in order to return the same `Observable<[Book]>` type without messing with nested observables and a zillion of compile time errors. I'm pretty sure this is a common scenario to use `flatMap` but it is still kind of obscure to me.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one should split the *Book* struct into two structs. The first one is called *BookInfo* here and an array of them is downloaded with calling the function *search*.

```
struct BookInfo {
    let title: String
    let authors: [String]
    let coverImageURL: URL
}
```

Composing a *BookInfo* instance together with the coverImage data could result in *Book* struct like this:

```
struct Book {
    let bookInfo: BookInfo
    let coverImage: Data
}
```

The RxSwift chain would look like this:

```
self.search(query: "<someQuery>") 
.flatMap { (bookInfos: [BookInfo]) -> Observable<BookInfo> in
    Observable.from(bookInfos)
}
.flatMap { (bookInfo: BookInfo)  -> Observable<Book> in
    //use the coverImageURL from the closure parameter and fetch the coverImage
    //return an Observable<Book>  
}
.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
.do(onNext: { (book: Book) in
    //e.g. add a book in main thread to the UI once the cover image is available
})
.subscribe()
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Instead of using type inference I added explicit type specifications, so it is more obvious what kind of elements are passed through the chain.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use just one *Book* struct, you could use this:

```
self.search(query: "<someQuery>") 
.flatMap { (books: [Book]) -> Observable<Book> in
    Observable.from(books)
}
.flatMap { (book: Book)  -> Observable<Book> in
    //use the book.coverImageURL from the closure parameter and fetch the coverImage
    //since the closure parameter 'book' is a let constant you have to construct a new Book instance 
    //return an Observable<Book>     
}
...
```

Please note that the closure parameters are *let* constants. This means that you cannot change the *coverImage* property even though it is defined as *var* in the structure. Instead, you must create a new instance of the Book structure, fill it with the values from the Closure parameter, and add the *coverImage* data. Accordingly, if you want to go this route, you could also optionally change *coverImage* to be a *let* constant.

I guess I personally would a have a slight preference for the first approach with the two structs.

Comment: Great approach, I like it :D I will give it a try. Let me wait for someone answering without using two structs before accepting your answer.

Comment: Glad you like it :D. I updated the answer and added a second approach without using two structs.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it is what I was looking for :)